# Making only one task run at a time in celerybeat

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I have a task which I execute once a minute using celerybeat. It works fine. Sometimes though, the task takes a few seconds more than a minute to run because of which two instances of the task run. This leads to some race conditions that mess things up.

I can (and probably should) fix my task to work properly but I wanted to know if celery has any builtin ways to ensure this. My cursory Google searches and RTFMs yielded no results.

Comment: I solved it, with using something like pid-file, When task eecuted creates file, when stops delete file. Is not perfect solution, but working ok

Answer (score 2):

You could [add a lock](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time), using something like memcached or just your db.

Comment: This is a good solution.  Just curious, why are they using those lambdas in the example?  Why not call `add` and `delete` directly?  Just to convey semantics, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a cron schedule or time interval for run periodic tasks you will still have the problem. You can always use a lock mechanism using a db or cache or even filesystem or also schedule the next task from the previous one, maybe not the best approach.
This question can probably help you:
[django celery: how to set task to run at specific interval programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172584/django-celery-how-to-set-task-to-run-at-specific-interval-programmatically)

Comment: Just for reference, I'm pretty sure time intervals execute the task a certain amount of time after it last _started_ execution, not _finished_ execution.  In fact, I think Celerybeat doesn't even track the tasks after they're sent out for execution.

Comment: @nitwit you are completely right. In my answer I say "after the last execution" I don't say after the finished execution. :-)
Is also true that I'm wrong to say "this shouldn't happen" I will edit it the answer accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a classfield to the object that holds the function that youre making run and use that field as a "some other guy is working or not" control

Comment: I can think of lots of ways by changing my code. I want to know if celerybeat provides something like this by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The lock is a good way with either beat or a cron.

But, be aware that beat jobs **run at worker start time**, not at beat run time.

This was causing me to get a race condition even with a lock. Lets say the worker is off and beat throws 10 jobs into the queue. When celery starts up with 4 processes, all 4 of them grab a task and in my case 1 or 2 would get and set the lock at the same time.

Solution one is to use a cron with a lock, as a cron will execute at that time, not at worker start time.

Solution two is to use a slightly more advanced locking mechanism that handles race conditions. For redis look into [setnx](http://redis.io/commands/setnx), or the newer [redlock](http://redis.io/topics/distlock).
This blog post is really good, and includes a decorator pattern that uses redis-py's locking mechanism: http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html.