# django celery: how to set task to run at specific interval programmatically

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I found that I can set the task to run at specific interval at specific times from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990531/how-can-i-schedule-a-task-to-execute-at-a-specific-time-using-celery), but that was only done during task declaration. How do I set a task to run periodically dynamically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The schedule is [derived from a setting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), and thus seems to be immutable at runtime.

You can probably accomplish what you're looking for using [Task ETAs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown). This guarantees that your task won't run *before* the desired time, but doesn't promise to run the task at the designated time—if the workers are overloaded at the designated ETA, the task may run later.

If that restriction isn't an issue, you could write a task which would first run itself like:

```
@task
def mytask():
    keep_running = # Boolean, should the task keep running?
    if keep_running:
        run_again = # calculate when to run again
        mytask.apply_async(eta=run_again)
    # ... do the stuff you came here to do ...
```

The major downside of this approach is that you are relying on the taskstore to remember the tasks in flight. If one of them fails before firing off the next one, then the task will never run again. If your broker isn't persisted to disk and it dies (taking all in-flight tasks with it), then none of those tasks will run again.

You could solve these issues with some kind of transaction logging and a periodic "nanny" task whose job it is to find such repeating tasks that died an untimely death and revive them.

If I had to implement what you've described, I think this is how I would approach it.

Comment: Yes, the scheduler is not optimised for dynamic schedules, but you can implement your own `Schedule` with an `is_due` method as described above, also having the task reschedule itself is an option many use, but then you need to ensure the first task is always triggered, which isn't that easy.  Another option is to use the DatabaseScheduler in django-celery, this does support dynamic schedules, and can also be used outside of Django projects.  In addition, creating your own schedulers is not that hard.

Comment: @asksol, the documentations for django-celery is empty. where can i find out on how to use the databaseScheduler?

Comment: @amateur Well, the documentation is really scarce here:

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes   Then you go the Django-Admin interface and add periodic tasks, or you can modify the periodic task models directly.

Comment: But changing the interval of a PeriodicTask does not immediately have effect. I find that enable/disabling a PeriodicTask is required for the changes to be noticed.

Answer (score 2):

`celery.task.base.PeriodicTask` defines `is_due` which determines when the next run should be. You could override this function to contain your custom dynamic running logic. See the docs here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.task.base.html?highlight=is_due#celery.task.base.PeriodicTask.is_due

An example:

```
import random
from celery.task import PeriodicTask

class MyTask(PeriodicTask):

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
        logger.info("Running my task")

    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        # Add your logic for when to run. Mine is random
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            # Run now and ask again in a minute
            return (True, 60)
        else:
            # Don't run now but run in 10 secs
            return (True, 10)
```

Comment: can u give me an example of how to override during runtime? I presume i can't use .delay since there is no run() for periodicTask classes

Comment: You define your own schedule class (celery.schedules.schedule) with a custom is_due method.  `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {"my name": {"task": "myapp.mytask", schedule": myschedule()}}`

Answer (score 0):

see here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

i think you can't make it dynamically ... best way is create task in task :D

for example you want run something for X sec later then you create new task with x sec delay and in this task create another task for N*X sec delay ...

Answer (score 0):

This should help you some... http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-change-the-interval-of-a-periodic-task-at-runtime

Once you've defined a custom schedule, assign it to your task as asksol has suggested above.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {    
    "my_name": {
        "task": "myapp.tasks.task",
        "schedule": myschedule(),    
    }
}
```

You might also want to modify CELERYBEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL if you want your schedule to update more often than every five minutes.