# run celery tasks in random times

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

i need to run few celery tasks in random times - every run should be at a new random time - the random number should generated every run. 
what I did in the past is:

```
 "my_task": {
     "task": "path.to.my_task",
     "schedule": crontab(minute='*/%s' % rand),
 },
rand = random(1,12)
```

but this code is not good for my needs anu more:
1. I need different (as possible with random0 number for each tenant 
2. different number will generated every time and not only on settings.py load (once)

I tried to overwrite Schedule as explained in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172584/django-celery-how-to-set-task-to-run-at-specific-interval-programmatically) answer but it did not work, is there better way? am I missing something?

(for example in tenant A the task will run at 23 and the day after at 8, and in tenant B the task will run at 4 and the day after at 20 etc)

Thanks!

======== update ====

after the great answer I got, I added option to my task and process it in apply_asynch method as suggested- 
.

```
"my-task": {  # deprecated task
               "task": "mdm_sync.tasks.test_task",
               # "schedule": new_sc(),
               "schedule": crontab(minute=39, hour=11),
                "options": {
                    "eta": datetime.utcnow()
                }
},
```

```
entry.options["eta"] = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=random(3600,12*3600)
```

works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem in which i had to generate **facebook** like notifications between **random users** at **random interval of time**

Initially i was also doing the same as you, using the `random` function to give the `minute` value to `crontab`. But, as `settings.py` and `celery.py` are loaded only once when you hit `python manage.py runserver`, that random function runs only once and hence that random value is selected only once, say **5 minutes** or **7 minutes**, but then this random value is used for repeating the task at every 5 or 7 minutes, hence making the tasks **repeat periodically**.

So, what you need to do is that instead of defining the timing of task in `settings.py` or `celery.py` you need to **recursively** call the function/ method in your `tasks.py`. But the key here is that you need to call the same function **recursively and asynchronously**, and while calling it asynchronously, you need to pass a parameter **delay** whose value will be calculated by using the **random function**

See my `tasks.py` -> https://github.com/ankushrgv/notification/blob/master/apps/notifications/tasks.py

And

`celery.py` -> https://github.com/ankushrgv/notification/blob/master/config/celery.py

You'll have to `python manage.py shell` and then call the function / method from there only once to start the recursion.

something like

```
`myFunction().apply_async()`
```

In my case it used to be

```
`CreateNotifications().apply_async()`
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)